# Routing API Routes in Golang

Tags: rest, go, routes

I want to be able to organize all my routes by separate folders and route accordingly.  So that means that instead of having all my HandleFunc's in one area (and have 50 routes in one file) I can route all my 'user' API routes to a user directory where they'd get further routed to 'user' functionality, I could route all my 'messages' API route to a 'messages' directory where they'd get further routed to 'messages' functionality, etc.
So if someone goes to to localhost:5000/api/routes/user/getUser I would direct them to another router in /api/routes/users which would then route to GetUserHandler().

What I currently have

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func GetUserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Got a user"))
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("api/routes/getUser", GetUserHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}
```

What I'm trying to do

```
// api/routes/user.go
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)


// somehow route /getUser to this function
func GetUserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Got a user"))
}
```

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // somehow route to to all my user functions
    // the 'User' here is just an example to help illustrate my point
    r.HandleFunc("api/routes/user", User)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you're asking, but a Subrouter might be what you want.

Comment: What's your question? I don't see any problem with the way you want to do it, other than you're not importing/referencing `GetUserHandler` properly.

Comment: Instead of having a  file containing 50 different routes, it would be good to have one handler for all user routes which can route to another route which handles all my users functionality, same for messages, etc.  Does that make more sense?  That way I could have a file with a few different "main" routes for user, messages, etc which would route to another directory containing all their functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT separate them physically, but can separate them logically (to increase readability):

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/account/{key}", AccountHandler)
r.HandleFunc("/category/{key}", CategoryHandler)
```

If you look at the above code, this is required for registering routes (as you already know :-)). So there is a pattern here, which will help to separate the routes to their respective folders. You can use map feature of Golang by defining routes as key and functions as values. This way instead of writing 100 of routes to a single file, you can write them to their respective folders.

I did write an example for logical separation: https://gitlab.com/nerdyram/test-gorilla-mux